# Rotate discrete Points in Java without conflicts

Tags: java, math, rotation, point

I am generating a List of points that have only integer components using GenerateSolidThetaZero function. My goal is to rotate these discrete points using an angle theta in radians and the new point after the rotation should still have integer components. The problem is I do not want any two points mapping to the same value. I want the same number of unique points before and after the rotation. I used the round function to remedy this problem a bit but I will still get some non-unique mappings. Basically I just want to find a way to rotate these points and preserve as much of the structure as possible(losing the least amount of points as possible). I am willing to use any library. Any help or guidance would be great.

Note: In my code the radius is 2 and 13 points are generated. After the rotation of Pi/6 I end up losing 4 points due to those points mapping to the same value another point already mapped to.

```
    public class pointcheck{
        // this HashSet will be used to check if a point is already in the rotated list
        public static HashSet<Point> pointSet = new HashSet<Point>();

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            //generates sort of circular solid with param being the radius
            ArrayList<Point> solid_pointList =  GenerateSolidThetaZero(2);

            //used to store original point as first part of pair and rotated point as second part of pair
            ArrayList<Pair> point_pair = new ArrayList<Pair>();

            //goes through all points in Solid_pointList adds each point to Point List with its corresponding rotated angle
            for(Point t : solid_pointList){
                point_pair.add(new Pair(t,rotation_about_origin(t,Math.PI / 6)));
            }

            for(Pair t : point_pair){
                System.out.println(t.getFirst() + "   " + t.getSecond());
            }

            System.out.println(pointSet.size());

        }

        //takes the point we want to rotate and then the angle to rotate it by
        public static Point rotation_about_origin(Point P, double theta){
            Point new_P = null;
            double old_X = P.x;
            double old_Y = P.y;
            double cos_theta = Math.cos(theta);
            double sin_theta = Math.sin(theta);
            double new_X = old_X * cos_theta - old_Y * sin_theta;
            double new_Y = old_X * sin_theta + old_Y * cos_theta;

            new_P = new Point((int)Math.round(new_X),(int)Math.round(new_Y));

            //if new_p is already in rotated solid
            if(pointSet.contains(new_P))
                System.out.println("Conflict       " + P + "          " + new_P);
            else
                //add new_P to pointSet so we know a point already rotated to that spot
                pointSet.add(new_P);
            return new_P;
        }


        private static ArrayList<Point> GenerateSolidThetaZero(int r){
            int rsq = r * r;
            ArrayList<Point> solidList=new ArrayList<Point>();
            for (int x=-r;x<=r;x++)
                for (int y=-r;y<=r;y++)
                    if (x*x + y*y <= rsq)
                        solidList.add(new Point(x,y));

            return solidList;
        }

    public static class Pair<F,S>{
        private F first; //first member of pair
        private S second; //second member of pair

        public Pair(F first, S second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public void setFirst(F first) {
            this.first = first;
        }

        public void setSecond(S second) {
            this.second = second;
        }

        public F getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public S getSecond() {
            return second;
        }
      }
    }//end of pointcheck class
```

How would I be able to rotate the points using angles that aren't using integer multiples of 90? Where should I translate a point after rotation if the mapping is already taken?

Comment: Just use any integer multiple of 90° as the rotation angle.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will only be limited to those angles.

Comment: So? Is there any specific question here?

Comment: How would I be able to rotate the points using angles that aren't using integer multiples of 90? Where should I translate a point after rotation if the  mapping is already taken?

Comment: Could you add some more context? What do you need this for? You could just move overlapping points to non-occupied cells. But since a disk is rotation-invariant, this will result in the same disk again if done properly.

Comment: I don't understand how 2 points could map to the same point under rotation. Please give an example input of points and angle, and example output of what you get and what you want to get instead.

Comment: @user1803551 The overlapping mapping is caused by the rounding step. For the desired result, I am also not sure.

Comment: Lets just say these coordinates give us locations of pixels on an image in the shape of a disk and lets say each pixel has a unique color. My question is what should my convention be for moving the overlapping points if I want the a group of pixels to still be next each other after rotation.

Comment: The usual approach is to interpolate colors at the new pixel positions. Is that a viable approach for your scenario or do you need to preserve the colors?

Comment: I need to preserve the colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotated disk will cover the exact same pixels as the original one. Therefore, you actually want to solve an assignment problem from original pixels to rotated pixels.

The cost for assigning an original pixel `(ox, oy)` to a corresponding pixel `(cx, cy)` can be expressed with a potential. For example, the distance:

```
E_o,c = length(R(ox, oy, theta) - (cx, cy))
```

, where `R` is the rotation operator. Alternatively, you could also try other norms, e.g. the quadratic distance.

Then, the problem is finding the correspondences that minimize the overall energy:

```
min_C Sum_{o \in O} E_o,c
```

An algorithm that solves this exactly is the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). However, it is quite expensive if you have a large number of pixels.

Instead, here is an idea of an approximation:

In the target pixels, instead of having only the color, also store the rotated position. Then, rotate the original pixels sequentially as you did before. Round the rotated position and check if the according pixel is still occupied.

If not, store the rotated (unrounded) position along with the new color.

If it is occupied, check if the energy would decrease if you swapped the correspondences. If it does, swap them, which leaves you with the former pixel. In any case, you have an unmapped original pixel. Store this pixel in a list.

After this procedure, you have a partial correspondence map and a list of unmapped pixels. Pick any of the unmapped pixels. Analyze the target pixel's neighbors. There will probably always be an unoccupied pixel (although I have no proof for that). If so, choose this one. If not, check all neighboring pixels for the best energy decrease and swap. Continue until the list is empty.

The approximation algorithm is just an idea and I have no proof that it will actually work. But it sounds as if it is worth a try. And it will definitely be faster than the Hungarian algorithm. Though, this approximation will only work with Lp-norms having p>=1 for the potential definition.